# Privilege Access Levels

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation

I noticed that recently there was an update in the privilege accessibility.

I was wondering what is the point of putting a relatively usable privilege so far high, that at the current time of writing there is only one non-moderator user that can use this feature?

I'm talking of course on approving Tag Wikis. Naturally, this is not something to take lightly but I don't see the point of making this feature "inaccessible" (in the large-cardinal meaning) and keep pushing it further away from users. This sort of update should be made after there is a core of users with high/close enough reputation.

This isn't the case, I believe, at the time of posting.

Might I request that this privilege be set (for the time being, at least) to a lower threshold which will allow more than one person to use it? (I'm guessing that 10k is a good starting point, maybe even low as 7.5k?)

Comment: Approving Tag Wikis requires only 5000. So there is more than one non-moderator on this site with access it: 18 people at this moment if I count correctly.

Comment: @Asaf: Do you perhaps mean "Trusted User" priviledges, which requires 20,000? (I'm guessing *I'm* the "non-moderator user"). That includes *editing* tag wikis, so perhaps that is what you were refering to?

Comment: As far as I know, only one person has even bothered to edit a tag wiki.

Comment: @Qiaochu: http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/tag-wikis gives you a list of tags which have been edited.

Comment: @Qiaochu: Well, I just bothered with a couple... probably not a good enough job, just getting my feet wet.

Comment: I am almost completely certain that editing tag wikis required 20k a few hours ago. Either that, or I was having one of them crazy Mondays again. :-)

Comment: I knew it: "There is no tag wiki for this tag.

Tag wikis help introduce newcomers to the tag. They contain an overview of the topic defined by the tag, along with guidelines on its usage.

Tag wikis can be edited by users with more than 20000 reputation.

All registered users may propose new tag wikis for peer review"

Comment: @asaf any registered user can propose tag edits

Answer (score 3):

I think you misunderstand.

Any user may *propose a suggested edit* either to a post or a tag wiki.

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/

*Approving* these edits requires 2k (for posts) or 5k (for tag wiki) reputation.

20k users have the privilege of unfettered editing to tag wikis without needing the approval of any other users.

Comment: I am almost 100% positive that I saw the approving tag wiki edits sitting on the top of the list with 20k rep.